# Is there any way to get rid of " ' " in a list in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a csv file which contains such data in a column:

```
4,90,1,228 
31,828 
3,110,1,540 
3,110,1,540 
111,350 
3,308,1,780     
3,369,1,2409 
0,1350 
7,132 
11,210 
4,2240,8,3720
```

I tried to assign this data to a list object named "`jobs_data1`" while adjusting them in the desired way shown down below.

Here is the desired output of `print(jobs_data1)`:

```
[[(4, 90), (1, 228)], [(3, 1828)], [(3, 110), (1, 540)], [(3, 110), (1, 540)], [(11, 1350)], [(3, 308), (1, 780)], [(3, 369), (1, 2409)], [(0, 1350)], [(7, 132)], [(11, 210)], [(4, 2240), (8, 3720)]]
```

This is the code:

```
    with open("jobs.csv") as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
            jobs_data1 = [[tuple(row[i : i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(row), 2)] for row in csv_reader]
           
            print(jobs_data1)
            print(type(jobs_data1))
   csv_file.close()
```

This is the output:

```
    [[('4', '90'), ('1', '228')], [('3', '1828')], [('3', '110'), ('1', '540')], [('3', '110'), ('1', '540')], [('11', '1350')], [('3', '308'), ('1', '780')], [('3', '369'), ('1', '2409')], [('0', '1350')], [('7', '132')], [('11', '210')], [('4', '2240'), ('8', '3720')]]

<class 'list'>
```

However, I want to get rid of " ' " in the output of the "jobs_data1" variable while keeping the type of the variable in list format.
Are there any other reading file ways to reach the desired output?

Comment: The `'` indicate that they're _strings_, you can parse those strings to integers, which don't have quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to change the type from string to int for all elements in the tuple. For the same, you can use the map function.

```
with open("jobs.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    jobs_data1 = [[tuple(map(int, row[i : i + 2])) for i in range(0, len(row), 2)] for row in csv_reader]
    
    print(jobs_data1)
```

Also, since you are using `with open ()`, using `csv_file.close()` is not required

Answer (score 0):

Removing the ' means converting the string to an integer. You can easily achieve this with the int() function:

```
with open("jobs.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        jobs_data1 = [[tuple(int(row[i : i + 2])) for i in range(0, len(row), 2)] for row in csv_reader]
       
        print(jobs_data1)
        print(type(jobs_data1))
csv_file.close()
```